# Reading CSV file in WinPython

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I want to merge two CSV files in Spyder,

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = pd.readcsv('C:/Rdata/plant1.csv')
data2 = pd.readcsv('C:/Rdata/Species.csv')
newdata = pd.merge(data1, data2, on='Speies')
```

but got this error:

```
………………………………, line 9, in <module>
data1 = pd.readcsv('C:/Rdata/plant1.csv')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'readcsv'
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously there is not any function named as 'readcsv'. This is [read_csv.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = pd.read_csv('C:/Rdata/plant1.csv')
data2 = pd.read_csv('C:/Rdata/Species.csv')
newdata = pd.merge(data1, data2, on='Speies')
```